# Moving social networks cookies from one container to another (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, browser, web, cookies

I want to move cookies of web.telegram.org and web.whatsapp.com and from one container to another in Firefox, I used the addon "Cookie Quick Manager", it lets you copy cookies from a container to another and it normally works (I tried with superuser.com) but it doesn't with these two websites; my question is: Do I need to move something else apart from cookies and is it possible?

What I tried:

- I moved whatsapp cookies to another container (and it didn't work), then I moved the cookies again to the original container and it worked normally, so I think there is some other "security check" implemented in the website that is connected with the container.

Notes:
If that matters, the original container is the "Default" container and the new one is the "Personal" container

Comment: Try turning off [Enhanced Tracking Protection](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enhanced-tracking-protection-firefox-desktop) when importing the cookies.

Comment: @harrymc I just tried but it doesn't work for me (I disabled the protection and then imported the cookies to the new container)